# Filament not updating in Repetier-Host.85B

Tags: printing, 3d

I was printing a model of the Hoover tower I got off of thingiverse. The print went fine but after printing 120 of the 900 layers the live update of the print stopped showing on the software. On the manual control tab it usually shows for the picture the progress of the printing. I got two errors when this happened saying "Disabled additional filament drawings for better framerate and print quality. You can re-enable this by going to Config -> Repitier Settings -> Behavior" The only option under behavior is Disable Quality Reduction which seems to have no bearing on the live feed of the progress of the print.